# How to read binary file in to a 100 bytes length array

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I want to read a binary file in to a byte array, not in to a single byte array
but in to a 100 bytes length array, maybe with a loop...

```
public void readBinaryFile()
    {
        byte data[] = null;
        try {
            Path path1 = Paths.get("image.jpg");
            data = Files.readAllBytes(path1);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("file reading error!!!");
        }

        System.out.println("img length: "+data.length);

    }
```

Comment: I think you should look here for http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/inputstream_read_byte.htm

Answer (score 0):

I use for such purposes my [JBBP library](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser) which allows to parse binary file partially ad to read only header for instance, you can find some examples of usage in [tests of the library](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser/tree/master/src/test/java/com/igormaznitsa/jbbp/it)